# Join 2 tables on multiple columns and pull values based on each join

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with product and top 5 competitors 
we have thousands of products and competitors could be part of our own products

```
product     comp 1  comp 2  comp 3  comp 4  comp 5
A           B       C       D       E       F
```

I need to pull their sales values for each competitor

```
Product Sales
A       10
B       20
C       30
D       40
E       50
F       60
```

In order to pull sales for comp 1,2,3,4 and 5 I would have to join product table with sales table 5 times on different column , also there will be issues while combining(union) all these tables together as sales for all competitors must be different col e.g. comp1 sales, comp 2 sales , comp 3 sales and so on

```
product comp 1 comp 2 comp 3 comp 4 comp 5 comp 1 sales comp 2 sales comp 3 sales comp 4 sales  comp 5 sales
A   B   C   D   E   F   20  30  40  50  60
```

Is there any other way of joining the tables to get the desired output ?

Comment: What is the meaning of product A having its own sales data, not related to an actual salesperson?  Can you better explain the logic behind your table design?

Comment: The idea here is to pull sales numbers for product and its competitors. We have thousands of products and top 5 competitor for each product in our product table. It has nothing to do with salesperson. A,B,C,D,E,F are all items in this case.

Comment: Please tag **only** the RDBMS you are interested in, not all of them.

Comment: Are sales, Competitor and Product three different tables?

Comment: There are 2 tables - Product and competitors (table 1) and product sales(table 2). I need to pull sales info from product sales table into table 1 for each of top 5 competitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a single `JOIN` with an `IN` condition, and then do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    p.product,
    p.comp1,
    p.comp2,
    p.comp3,
    p.comp4,
    p.comp5,
    MAX(CASE WHEN s.product = p.comp1 THEN s.sales END) comp1sales,
    MAX(CASE WHEN s.product = p.comp2 THEN s.sales END) comp2sales,
    MAX(CASE WHEN s.product = p.comp3 THEN s.sales END) comp3sales,
    MAX(CASE WHEN s.product = p.comp4 THEN s.sales END) comp4sales,
    MAX(CASE WHEN s.product = p.comp5 THEN s.sales END) comp5sales
FROM product p
INNER JOIN sales s 
    ON s.product IN (p.comp1, p.comp2, p.comp3, p.comp4, p.comp5)
GROUP BY
    p.product,
    p.comp1,
    p.comp2,
    p.comp3,
    p.comp4,
    p.comp5
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid 5 joins you can use UNION to convert column into row:

```
  SELECT
     p.product,
     p.comp
    FROM(
    SELECT
     p.product,
     compA AS comp
    FROM(
    -- this is your product table
    SELECT '1' AS product, 'A' AS compA, 'B' AS compB, 'C' AS compC
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2' AS product, 'E' AS compA, 'F' AS compB, 'G' AS compC
    )p

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
     p.product,
     compB AS comp
    FROM(
    -- this is your product table
    SELECT '1' AS product, 'A' AS compA, 'B' AS compB, 'C' AS compC
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2' AS product, 'E' AS compA, 'F' AS compB, 'G' AS compC
    )p

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
     p.product,
     compC AS comp
   FROM(
    -- this is your product table
    SELECT '1' AS product, 'A' AS compA, 'B' AS compB, 'C' AS compC
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2' AS product, 'E' AS compA, 'F' AS compB, 'G' AS compC
    )p

) p
INNER JOIN (
    -- Sales table
    SELECT 'A' as comp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B' as comp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C' as comp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'D' as comp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'E' as comp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'F' as comp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'G' as comp
) sales ON p.comp = sales.comp;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/109833